# Rails convert memory address to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bit of code that calls a Sidekiq worker like this.
`NotifySubscriberWorker.perform_async(@incident)`.

`@incident` is a object of class Incident (which is a model). However, in my mailer, when I try to perform operations like `@incident.created_at`, this is what I get.
`ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'updated_at' for "#<Incident:0x007f31ccd5f020>":String`

I'm assuming that for some reason `@incident` isn't being passed around as an Incident. Here's my worker's code.

```
class NotifySubscriberWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(incident)
    # Notify all activated subscribers when there's an update to an incident
    Subscriber.where(activated: true).find_each do |subscriber|
      # Schedule the mail
      SubscriberMailer.notify_subscriber(subscriber, incident)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the mailer's code.

```
class SubscriberMailer < ApplicationMailer
  @@app_name = APP_CONFIG['name']
  def activate_subscriber(subscriber)
    @activation_url = root_url + "subscribers/activate/#{subscriber.activation_key}"
    mail to: subscriber.email, subject: "Please confirm your subscription for #{@@app_name}'s incidents."
  end
  def notify_subscriber(subscriber, incident)
    @incident = incident
    mail to: subscriber.email, subject: "There is an update to #{@@app_name}'s status.'"
  end
end
```

The view attempts to access `@incident` from the definition above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your controller and view code?

Comment: @shivam, I'd have given a GitHub link, but my code is uncommited and I can't push now. Updated the question with the mailer's code.

Comment: I suspect `incident` parameter is a string. Did you check `puts @incident.inspect` after creating the instance variable?

Comment: Yeah @shivam, `.class` says it's a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass an object_id instead of whole object to your worker.

Call worker:

`NotifySubscriberWorker.perform_async(@incident.id)`

Then change in your worker:

`SubscriberMailer.notify_subscriber(subscriber, incident_id)`

and then in mailer:

```
  def notify_subscriber(subscriber, incident_id)
    @incident = Incident.find(incident_id)
    mail to: subscriber.email, subject: "There is an update to #{@@app_name}'s status.'"
  end
```

Comment: Will mark it correct as soon as SO will let me do that